# Which assemblers are used on M1 Macs ? Where is the canonical documentation?

Tags: macos, assembly, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'd like to get a better idea which assemblers are actually working on M1/M2 MacOs machines, such as MacBook Pros.

1. As I understand it, the only possible assembler I can use is the Apple provided 'as'. Gnu Assembler ('gas') is no longer supported on M1+ machines: 'as -Q' says so. But many websites mention that the Apple assembler is really not maintained, and that there is a switch to llvm-clang assembler, for which I find no useful documentation (for running the assembler, not building a compiler).

True ?

2. I'm looking into documentation, and I mostly only find the "Mac OS X Assembler Guide". And a very old copy at that, I'm not even sure where to get a recent version.

That seems OK, but it seems not entirely complete – for instance, you can have macros with named parameters instead of just using $0, ... $n in 'as'. Not mentioned in the guide.

Are there any good pointers to porting from gas to the apple assembler ? Known problems and solutions ?

E.g., in 'gas', I believe I can redefine symbols with .set, but not with 'as'.
I'm really a very inexperienced assembler amateur, so some canonical resources would be great. As I see it today, assembly programming on M1 Mac's is more dark arts than a science.

Thanks for any enlightenment.

Comment: `as` on modern MacOS is clang / LLVM, which uses the same syntax and directives as the GNU assembler.  There might be some minor differences like you mention with `.set`.  And some of the directives it supports are specific to MachO object files.  Sorry, I don't know enough about MacOS to post a real answer.

Comment: Adding concrete links for what I found so far - most of them not very useful and outdated:

Outdated apple site that says 'do not use':

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/000-Introduction/introduction.html

This is Apple's new documentation site, where I did not find assembler details:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/application-binary-interfaces

Comment: This question is off topic for this forum.

Comment: @magnas Any suggestion on which stackoverflow forum would be 'on topic' ?

Comment: The guide you have is most probably useless. M1 is an ARM architecture. You should look for ARM64 (`aarch64` ISA) assembly tutorial.
BTW, llvm assembly is largely the same as gnu one. (very similar)

Comment: @Magnas: How so?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic explicitly mentions "software tools commonly used by programmers" as being on topic, and if an assembler isn't a software tool commonly used by programmers, I don't know what is.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to document what I found so far:

1. the [old assembler guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/000-Introduction/introduction.html) from apple is (per
   Jake 'Alquimista' LEE) most likely not useful, as this guide is most likely not based on the clang assembler used by M1 Macs). No new doc found on the new SDK site.

The documentation likely to be mostly accurate seems to be  https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100067/0611/armclang-Integrated-Assembler.

There's also https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100068/0612/migrating-from-armasm-to-the-armclang-integrated-assembler/symbol-definition-directives and https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100068/0612/migrating-from-armasm-to-the-armclang-integrated-assembler/overview-of-differences-between-armasm-and-gnu-syntax-assembly-code?lang=en

2. Most likely, Apple is using the clang assembler more or less directly. It is similar to the gnu assembler, but not identical. For instance, jonesforth uses a feature where you can .set a symbol over and over to non-absolute values like labels to build a linked list of commands - that works in GNU assembler, not in llvm (at least the apple assembler). Also, the apple assembler does not allow multiple statements in one line separated by ';', which is a huge pain in the neck when porting large assembly files making extensive use of this.
3. I believe that the llvm project has source code in github, specifically assembler parsing here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/92920c4fe3e29640e45153f3048105970b5b1e42/llvm/lib/MC/MCParser/AsmParser.cpp

I realize this is fairly incomplete, but I will update the answer should I ever get a useful response on the apple dev forums or directly from Apple support.

Comment: Mainline `-clang -target arm64  -c foo.s` assembles `mov w0, w1 ; mov w2, w3` ok, with `llvm-objdump -d` confirming that both instructions made it to the `.o` file.  Either Apple clang is different, or some of your statements include line-comments, or there are other cases I didn't test that don't work.  (Perhaps with some directives).

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to say. Apple's as is 'close' but not identical to mainline clang. That's what's so frustrating. I'm trying to get apple support to spit out the source to their as so I can see for myself.

FTR, using Apple's as will result in an a.out for which otool -tvV will only show one instruction.

Comment: Maybe `;` is a comment character for AArch64 (and perhaps x86-64?) in Apple-clang's version of `as`, like in x86 NASM / MASM (not GAS) syntax?  Can you put a `;` at the start of a line to ignore arbitrary stuff without error or effect, even things that wouldn't be valid?  Possibly there's some other non-newline statement separator, but you might just be out of luck.

Comment: I can use ';' as comment:
`; I am a little teapot`
`; ≈ no errors produced`
`mov w0, w1 ; mov w2, w3`

`% as test2.S`
`% otool -tvV a.out`
`a.out:`
`(__TEXT,__text) section`
`0000000000000000 mov w0, w1`


I really don't want to speculate anymore, as it's not a great use of our time. I hope Apple will ultimately tell us what they are _actually_ doing either by providing documentation or the source.